# What's wrong with my Groovy regex?

Tags: regex, string, groovy, patternsyntaxexception

Here's my code:

```
String myRegex = "*cow"
String name = "SHIRACOWPEPPER"
name = name.toLowerCase()

if(!name || name.matches(myRegex)) {
    return true
}
```

When I run this I get a `PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0 *cow ^` error. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` is a meta character which means 'zero or more times' the thing you matched before, but in this case there is nothing to match. This should probably work:

```
String myRegex = ".*cow"
String name = "SHIRACOWPEPPER"
name = name.toLowerCase()

if(!name || name.matches(myRegex)) {
    return true
}
```

For more information see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: You can also do `!name || name ==~ myRegex`

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to say `String myRegex = ".*cow"` which means *any number characters prior to cow that is the suffix*.